# AssetFile Descriptor is not working on SetDataSource

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to play audio through obb expansion file. The app crashes when I call a AssetFileDescriptor method.It gives an error from setDataSource

I have tried to insert FileInputStream and InputStream

```
public void getAssetFileDescriptor(String filePath){

        PackageManager pkmanager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo info;

        try{
            info = pkmanager.getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
        }catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        String thePackageName = mContext.getPackageName();
        int thePackageVer = info.versionCode;
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


        String zipFilePath = root.toString() + "/Android/obb/"+thePackageName+"/main."+
                thePackageVer+"."+thePackageName+".obb";

        try{
            ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile(zipFilePath);
            AssetFileDescriptor asd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(filePath);
            if(asd != null){
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(asd.getFileDescriptor(), asd.getStartOffset(), asd.getLength());
                asd.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(asd);`?

Comment: yeah, it seems like it doesnt work either.

Comment: whats the complete stacktrace then?

Comment: it doesnt seem to catch any.

Comment: you have a crash without any stacktrace?

Comment: oh, my bad. I thought you were talking about something else.

Comment: at RecyclerViewAdapter.getAssetFileDescriptor(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:95)
        at RecyclerViewAdapter$1.onClick(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:67)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6310)

Comment: and whats the line 95 in RecyclerViewAdapter.java"

Comment: mediaPlayer.setDataSource(asd.getFileDescriptor(), asd.getStartOffset(), asd.getLength());

Comment: is `at RecyclerViewAdapter.getAssetFileDescriptor(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:95)` really the first line of the stacktrace?

Comment: yeah, it says on the top:     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor, long, long)' on a null object reference

Comment: your `mediaPlayer` variable is simply null

Comment: ah, i feel stupid. Thanks for helping... fixed it.

Comment: sure, your welcome - next time read the stacktrace carefully - in 90% of cases it solves "stupid" bugs